# Display all posts from multiple firebase directories into recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm working on our thesis about classroom announcements and I got stuck into this.

In my database, I have decided to put posts of different users under several categories.

> Categories

[image]

> Categories displaying posts

[image]

So I have successfully displayed all the posts under one category (Class Announcements) only.

> Classroom Announcements

[image]

```
private RecyclerView postList;

private DatabaseReference database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addPost = findViewById(R.id.btnAddPost);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("St Isidore of Seville")
            .child("Posts").child("Classroom Announcements");

    postList = findViewById(R.id.postList);

    postList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options= new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(database, Post.class).build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_row, parent, false);

            return new PostViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Post model) {
            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            holder.setMessage(model.getMessage());
            holder.setDateCreated(model.getDateCreated());
        }
    };

    postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
```

The problem is that only announcements under "Classroom Announcements" are the only posts that could be displayed. How can I display all announcements such as those under "Bills", "Homeworks", "Others", etc...

Can I use something like

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("St Isidore of Seville")
            .child("Posts");
```

or as soon as possible put every category in the database into just one FirebaseRecyclerAdapter so that I can use their date to show the most recent post on the top?

Comment: if you used this `database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("St Isidore of Seville")
            .child("Posts");` what do you get?

Comment: I get blank 6 blank boxes, which should be my categories, but only blank.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FWL45AvZTO9wDkorMBQ5_XlOVU4q2LeU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getChildren()` twice, so please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postsRef = rootRef.child("St Isidore of Seville").child("Posts");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : ds.getChildren()) {
                Post model = child.getValue(Post.class);
                Log.d("TAG", model.getTitle() + " / " + model.getMessage() + " / " + model.getDateCreated());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
postsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: It worked, but I didn't use firebaseUI anymore cause I don't know how it really works. Plus, I only used for loop once, instead of using it twice. Thank you, it really helped me